# Is there a term for an instrumental descant?

Tags: terminology

There are many songs that have an instrument (my favorite usually involve a trumpet) playing a high melody (or maybe "melodic flourish") above the main melody. I would call this is a "descant", except that searches for that term yield almost exclusively postings/videos/recordings of vocal (generally religious) music.

Is there a separate term used to describe this when the descant is played by an instrument rather than sung?

For example:

- The trumpet part in this rendition of "Hark the Herald Angles", starting at [0:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ta5FTtsqf4k&t=15). This is actually described as a "trumpet descant", but looking for that term only seems to find religious music.
- The trumpet part in Sharkia's "Hips Don't Lie", starting at [0:29](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUT5rEU6pqM&feature=youtu.be&t=29).

Comment: Songs? What kind?

Comment: I've heard similar techniques in classical music, popular music, etc. I'll see if I can update the question with some particular examples.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there **is* a term to describe a descant that's played rather than sung.

You could call a descant a type of [counter-melody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-melody) - "*a sequence of notes, perceived as a melody, written to be played simultaneously with a more prominent lead melody.*" But *unlike* a counter-melody it's always pitched *above* the melody, and is restricted in having to accommodate the same number of syllables as the melody itself. And, because we mostly encounter descants in hymn-singing, they've got a reputation for being *glorious*. Counter-melodies generally manage to avoid that!

So when such a thing appears in "classical" music - and I'm struggling to think of an example, though they're surely common enough - it would probably be described as "**a descant-like counter-melody**."

That'd be a rather academic way to describe what the trumpeter's doing in that Shakira song! He/she could just be improvising it. But that's how the Whole Thing started a thousand years ago: with monks improvising counter-melodies to the plainchants!